# Recover POST in array loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have a form around a table with more than 10 lines, every line have 3 or 4 hidden inputs with a dynamical name. Like id_01, id_02, id_03 and name_01_, name_02, name_03...

And i am recovering the $_POST as a array after submit the form inside a foreach loop. And getting this result:

- id_01
- name_02
- tel_03
- id_04
- name_05
- tel_06
- id_07
- name_08
- tel_09

But i need to get "grouped" result:

- id_01
- name_01
- tel_01

...

- id_02
- name_02
- tel_02

This is my code before the form submit:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($apiResponse['response']['data']['data'] as $data) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align='center'>" . $data['Offer']['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>" . $data['Stat']['affiliate_id'] . "<input type='hidden' name='aff_id_" . $i++ . "' value='" . $data['Stat']['affiliate_id'] . "'></td>";
echo "<td align='center'>" . $data['Stat']['conversions'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center'>" . number_format(@($data['Stat']['payout']/$data['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "<input type='hidden' value='" . number_format(@($data['Stat']['payout']/$data['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "' name='payout_" . $i++ . "'></td>";
echo "<td align='center'>" . number_format(@($data['Stat']['revenue']/$data['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "<input type='hidden' value='" . number_format(@($data['Stat']['revenue']/$data['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "' name='revenue_" . $i++ . "'></td>";
echo "<td align='center'><input size='2 type='text' name='invalidar_" . $i++ . "'></tr>";

}
```

And this is how i'm recovering:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li>'. $key . ': '. $value . '</li>';
}
```

Someone have any idea how do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved, instead use `foreach` i've used `for`. Acess the `array` with some coding, and *voilà*.

```
 for ($i = 0, $size = count($apiResponse['response']['data']['data']); $i < $size; ++$i) {

    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Offer']['name'] . "<input type='hidden' name='info[".$i."][offer_id]' value='" . $apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['offer_id'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['affiliate_id'] . "<input type='hidden' name='info[".$i."][aff_id]' value='" . $apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['affiliate_id'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['conversions'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . number_format(@($apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['payout']/$apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "<input type='hidden' value='" . number_format(@($apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['payout']/$apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "' name='info[".$i."][payout]'></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . number_format(@($apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['revenue']/$apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "<input type='hidden' value='" . number_format(@($apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['revenue']/$apiResponse['response']['data']['data'][$i]['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "' name='info[".$i."][revenue]'></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'><input size='2 type='text' name='info[".$i."][invalidar]'></tr>";

}
```

The result is:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td align="center" class="sorting_1">Aasha - IN<input type="hidden" name="info[627][offer_id]" value="1048"></td><td align="center">1448<input type="hidden" name="info[627][aff_id]" value="1448"></td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center">0.00<input type="hidden" value="0.00" name="info[627][payout]"></td><td align="center">0.00<input type="hidden" value="0.00" name="info[627][revenue]"></td><td align="center"><input size="2 type=" text'="" name="info[627][invalidar]"></td></tr>
```

After the submit i recover using a `foreach`:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($_POST['info'] as $key => $array) {
    echo $i++;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Offer ID:';
    echo $array['offer_id'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Affiliate ID:';
    echo $array['aff_id'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Revenue:';
    echo $array['revenue']; 
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Payout:';
    echo $array['payout']; 
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Invalidar:';
    echo $array['invalidar']; 
    echo '<br><br>';
    sleep(2);
}
```

And finally my **result grouped**:

```
0
Offer ID:1048
Affiliate ID:1448
Revenue:0.00
Payout:0.00
Invalidar:

1
Offer ID:1048
Affiliate ID:1505
Revenue:1.44
Payout:0.72
Invalidar:

2
Offer ID:1048
Affiliate ID:1501
Revenue:1.44
Payout:0.72
Invalidar:

3
Offer ID:1048
Affiliate ID:1565
Revenue:1.44
Payout:1.12
Invalidar:

4
Offer ID:577
Affiliate ID:1026
Revenue:0.00
Payout:0.00
Invalidar:

5
Offer ID:1050
Affiliate ID:1565
Revenue:0.00
Payout:0.00
Invalidar:

6
Offer ID:1050
Affiliate ID:1501
Revenue:0.00
Payout:0.00
Invalidar:

7
Offer ID:1050
Affiliate ID:1505
Revenue:0.00
Payout:0.00
Invalidar:

8
Offer ID:1317
Affiliate ID:2
Revenue:0.00
Payout:0.00
Invalidar:

9
Offer ID:1317
Affiliate ID:1352
Revenue:10.84
Payout:7.22
Invalidar:
```

Thanks everyone for helping me. (:

Answer (score 0):

Don't give input names like 'tel_03', instead give the name 'tel[]'. This will make array of inputs. now $_POST['tel'] will give you array with all values. and inside that loop pass the key for other variables e.g $_POST['id'][$key], this will give you the value associated with $_POST['tel'][$key]. Bcoz they appeared in same row when you generated that form.

Comment: I've tried something like that yesterday, i'll try again. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $i = 0;

 foreach ($apiResponse['response']['data']['data'] as $data)
 {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td align='center'>" . $data['Offer']['name'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td align='center'>" . $data['Stat']['affiliate_id'] . "<input type='hidden' name='info[".$i."]['id']' value='" . $data['Stat']['affiliate_id'] . "'></td>";
     echo "<td align='center'>" . $data['Stat']['conversions'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td align='center'>" . number_format(@($data['Stat']['payout']/$data['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "<input type='hidden' value='" . number_format(@($data['Stat']['payout']/$data['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "' name='info[".$i."]['payout']'></td>";
     echo "<td align='center'>" . number_format(@($data['Stat']['revenue']/$data['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "<input type='hidden' value='" . number_format(@($data['Stat']['revenue']/$data['Stat']['conversions']),2,'.','.') . "' name='info[".$i."]['revenue']'></td>";
     echo "<td align='center'><input size='2 type='text' name='invalidar_" . $i++ . "'></tr>";

 }
```

Replace the above code.

In your receiving file, just print $_POST. You will get data in grouped.

Comment: For some reason, stop working. All the $i is being replaced by info[0]. When i put $i++, go to zero stack again. :/